# Google sheets and Bank Of Canada Valet API - how to import data monthly for USD/CAD

Tags: xml, google-sheets, xpath, google-sheets-formula

I managed to play around with the BoC Valet API in Google sheets to obtain daily USDCAD rate for a specific period.

```
=importxml("https://www.bankofcanada.ca/valet/observations/FXCADUSD/xml?start_date="&text(Q31,"YYYY-mm-dd")&"&end_date="&text(Q32,"YYYY-mm-dd"),"//o/@d | //o/v")
```

Now I wish to do this between two date but return monthly data.

```
=importxml("https://www.bankofcanada.ca/valet/observations/group/FX_RATES_MONTHLY/xml?start_date=2023-01-23&end_date=2023-07-19&order_dir=asc","//o/@d | //o/v")
```

The result with this query is all the monthly FX rates available. What xpath should I use in the Google sheets `xpath_query` field to filter this data for USDCAD only ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Can you test this one out:*

```js
=chooserows(wrapcols(importxml("https://www.bankofcanada.ca/valet/observations/group/FX_RATES_MONTHLY/xml?start_date=2023-01-23&end_date=2023-07-19&order_dir=asc","//o/@d|//v/@s|//o/v"),47),1,-1,-2)
```

[image]

***UPDATED ANSWER***:

```js
=let(Σ,importxml("https://www.bankofcanada.ca/valet/observations/group/FX_RATES_MONTHLY/xml?start_date=2023-01-01&end_date=2023-12-31&order_dir=asc","//o/@d|//v/@s|//o/v"),Λ,sequence(counta(Σ)),
     exch_,filter(Λ,xmatch(Σ,"FXMUSDCAD")),
     date_,filter(Λ,isdate_strict(Σ)),
     chooserows(Σ,sort({exch_;date_;exch_-1})))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that's a great step forward!
If I  try with different dates, I somehow get a column with FXMSGDCAD and the rest for USDCAD. Any idea why ? Specifically the month of september

Comment: Do try the updated answer

Comment: works perfectly  thank you so much!  I am wondering if there is a way to return the result by columns for consistency and to be able to run vlookups on the resulting data ? Thank you so much again it's very much appreciated

Comment: I found it! By combining both of your answers: =WRAPROWS(let(Σ,importxml("https://www.bankofcanada.ca/valet/observations/group/FX_RATES_MONTHLY/xml?start_date=2023-01-01&end_date=2023-12-31&order_dir=asc","//o/@d|//v/@s|//o/v"),Λ,sequence(counta(Σ)),
     exch_,filter(Λ,xmatch(Σ,"FXMUSDCAD")),
     date_,filter(Λ,isdate_strict(Σ)),
     chooserows(Σ,sort({exch_;date_;exch_-1}))),3,0)